# Can I default a system property for a constructor-arg in a spring config file?

Tags: spring, maven, constructor, properties

I have a spring config file which includes the following elements:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:default.properties"/>

<bean id="theVar" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="${varName}"/>
</bean>
```

"varName" is now moved from the properties file to a system property.  It is being added when I start a Maven build:

```
mvn clean install -DvarName=data
```

I want to also run my build without specifying varName:

```
mvn clean install
```

Is there some way to default varName in my spring config? Though this does not work, a conceptual example of what I am looking for is:

```
<bean id="theVar" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="${varName}" default="theDefaultValue"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Does it need to be a system property?  Can it just be specified in another file?

Comment: It needs to be dynamic at build time.  I'm open to suggestions on how.  I need to specify different values for varName when I invoke a build, and I need to also invoke a build without specifying varName.

Comment: Would specifying multiple properties files help?  The `location` element supports multiple files delimited by comma(,).  You can specify another file that has the 'system defaults' in it, and if it cannot be resolved by the `classpath:default.properties`, then it would attempt to resolve by the next properties file.

Comment: I am doing that in other configs.  The problem in this case is that it moves the responsibility of handling the variation to another system who then has to manage the file.  I would then have to find a way to update the file before any build.  It's easy to do on my local dev machine, but it is more difficult on a CI build server.  Handling this variation is easy on a CI build machine using a system property.

Comment: It looks like "systemPropertiesMode" may work.  Looking in to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that in spring v2.5+, if there is a system property defined, it can be used instead of a property defined in the properties file.  You just need to ensure the same name is used and that the 'override' option is enabled.

For example, given:

```
<!-- my spring config file -->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:default.properties" system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE"/>
```

And:

```
# default.properties file
theVariable=One
```

When I execute:

```
mvn clean install
```

"One" is picked-up for theVariable.  If I execute:

```
mvn clean install -DtheVariable=Two
```

"Two" is picked-up instead.

Answer (score 7):

Spring 3.0.x supports a syntax like this:

```
value="${varName:defaultValue}"
```

References:

- [SPR-4785](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-4785)
- [Changes in version 3.0.0.RC1 (2009-09-25)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/changelog.txt) *(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer supports "${myKey:myDefaultValue}" defaulting syntax)*

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure If this will help but if you are annotating classes and want a default value when a system property is not present this is what I currently do:

```
@Value("#{systemProperties['fee.cc']?:'0.0225'}")
public void setCcFeePercentage(BigDecimal ccFeePercentage) {
    this.setCcFeePercentage(ccFeePercentage);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done as @sebastien has described but in the configuration file as you want:

```
<bean id="theVar" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="#{systemProperties['varName'] == null ? 'default_value' : systemProperties['varName']}"/>
</bean>
```

If your `varName` variable is not present, default value will be set.